# Angular4 - check if nested object item is empty

Tags: angular, object, typeof

I'm checking if a nested object item named "token" is empty or not, in AngularIDE with Angular4

```
if (typeof this.user.data.token !== "undefined")
```

this is throwing `<Cannot read property 'token' of null>`

Should I necessarily check for every nested object existance?

Comment: you can use lodash for  checking nested properties

Comment: Can you make an example?

Comment: check for lodash get function in official docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to ...

```
if (this.user && this.user.data && this.user.data.token) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always keep in mind that ***undefined*** and ***null*** are different, when you see ***undefined*** it means that a variable was declared but it holds no value in it and ***null*** is an actual assignment value. Also undefined is a type and null is an object. So..

```
 if(!(this.user.data.token == null));
```

Should work for you, if you want to add some other conditions just and the operator `||` and type next condition.

If you're looking to check for undefined objects you can do something like

```
this.user.data.token != undefined && ...
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reusable helper function which checks if the nested key exists or not and returns a boolean value.

```
/**
* @param obj: to check the nested key
* @param args: array of location to the nested key to check ['parentNode', 'childNode', 'grandChildNode']
*/
checkNestedKey(obj, args) {
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (!obj || !obj.hasOwnProperty(args[i])) {
            return false;
        }
        obj = obj[args[i]];
    }
    return true;
}

// to check if value exist this.user.data.token
if (this.checkNestedKey(this.user, ['data', 'token'])) {
    // continue here
}
```